# CSS - Problems with element overlays

Tags: css, z-index

I have this application below:

https://jsfiddle.net/claudiopb/v76m1e52/3/

The menu rectangle that appears is NOT behaving the way I expected. I would like it to go under the header and not overlap this element. With these screen simulations that I posted below, I think it's easier to understand.

**Current behavior**

I have this menu below.

[image]

When I click the hamburger button.
The menu rectangle opens like this:[image]

**Expected behavior:**

I would like it to behave this way, overlapping the elements of the page, as is already happening, but I would like it to go behind the header.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="subcontainer">
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-branding">DEV.</a>
                    <ul class="nav-menu">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="hamburger">
                        <span class="bar"></span> 
                        <span class="bar"></span> 
                        <span class="bar"></span> 
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section id="home">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="subcontainer">
              <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    height: 1000vh;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #98dbc6;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;    
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;    
}

.container {
    width: 1600px;
    margin: auto;    
}

.subcontainer {
    width: 85%;
    margin: auto;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 30px;
    gap: 60px;
}

.nav-branding {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.hamburger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background-color: black;
}

#home {
    margin-top: 70px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100vh;
}

@media(max-width:1600px) {
    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media(max-width:1024px) {
    .hamburger {
        display: block;
    }

    .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }

    .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }

    .nav-menu {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: -100%;
        gap: 0;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #b0abab;
        width: 100%;       
        transition: 0.3s;
        z-index: -1;
    }


    .nav-item {
        margin: 16px 0;
    }

    .nav-menu.active {
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    hamburger.classList.toggle("active")
    navMenu.classList.toggle("active")
})

document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link").forEach(
    n => n.addEventListener("click", () => {

        hamburger.classList.remove("active");
        navMenu.classList.remove("active");
    })
)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match with the picture, I don't see any hamburger button. Have you considered adding margin-top to the sub-menu to offset the header height? That should work, unless you want the sub-menu to slide down from behind the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had just altered your html and CSS and as per your design hope this works. If you need this style only on mobile view don't forget to add media query to the additional styles I had added to the CSS in fiddle.

changes I had made

1. Wrapped branding logo and hamburger menu inside a div
2. Added additional CSS to the wrapper div and commented in the bottom of css field in the jsfiddle

`.head-wrapper{display: flex;justify-content: space-between;width: 100%;background-color: #98dbc6;padding-left: 7.5%;padding-right: 7.5%;min-height: 70px;align-items: center;}.subcontainer{width:100%;}`

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xhedzuc5/)